# Change Cloudinary's images from private to public

Tags: cloudinary

There are 3 types of privacy for images uploaded to Cloudinary: http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/23183603-Does-Cloudinary-support-uploading-private-images-

How can I change a private image to be public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on Cloudinary's road map to support changing between public and private file types.
Currently you can re-upload private images as public images (using Cloudinary URLs as input for upload). 
Another option is to enable '**Strict Transformations**' mode (From the Dashboard's settings page) and use our `explicit` API to create the required derived images without allowing the transformation globally. 
Here's the 'explicit' documentation (PHP):
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload#refresh_images

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer was in 2013.

We don’t need to re-upload the assets anymore for that!

So I am updating here for anyone who stumbles on this in more recent times.

To make an asset *public* to *private* or vice-versa on Cloudinary,
we can use the [rename](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#rename_method) method of `uploader` as neatly suggested in this [Cloudinary Support link](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008318659-How-can-I-make-a-public-asset-private-).

In PHP:

```
$result = \Cloudinary\Uploader::rename($from_public_id, $to_public_id, $options = []);
```